# Wordpress doesn't recognize AJAX code (Enfold theme)

Tags: customization, reset-password

I'm trying to customize the "lost password" area in my Wordpress theme, called Enfold. Everything it's ok, so my code sends a link to a "new password introduction" area correctly to users email.
The link is: /new-password/?action=rp&key=TDeJEj7vVmmmJqbd&login=my_username

But when the user clicks on this link and the code redirects him to a "[new password introduction]/[repeat password]" area, the button who execute AJAX code after user write his new password and password confirmation is not responding.

I've added the wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script to functions.php but I think probably here's my error. I've added it this way:

```
if(!function_exists('avia_register_frontend_scripts'))
{
if(!is_admin()){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'avia_register_frontend_scripts');
}

function avia_register_frontend_scripts()
{
    $template_url = get_template_directory_uri();
    $child_theme_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

    //register js
    wp_register_script( 'avia-compat', $template_url.'/js/avia-compat.js', array('jquery'), 1, false ); //needs to be loaded at the top to prevent bugs
    wp_register_script( 'avia-default', $template_url.'/js/avia.js', array('jquery'), 1, true );
    wp_register_script( 'avia-shortcodes', $template_url.'/js/shortcodes.js', array('jquery'), 1, true );
    wp_register_script( 'avia-prettyPhoto',  $template_url.'/js/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', 'jquery', "3.1.5", true);
    // wp_register_script( 'wp-mediaelement',  $template_url.'/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js', 'jquery', "1", true);
    wp_register_script( 'discount',  $template_url.'/js/discount.js', 'javascript', "1", true);
    wp_register_script( 'reset_user_pass',  $template_url.'/js/reset-user-pass.js','jquery', "1", true );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'avia-compat' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'avia-default' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'avia-shortcodes' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'avia-prettyPhoto' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reset_user_pass' );
```

Here is the "[new password introduction]/[repeat password]" form code:

```
<?php 
/*Load Scripts for password reset page*/
wp_enqueue_script( 'zxcvbn-async' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'user-profile' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'password-strength-meter' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'user-suggest' );
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php" id="resetpassform" name="resetpassform">

<input type="hidden" name="login" value="<?php echo $_GET['login'] ?>" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_GET['key']); ?>" />

<p style="margin-bottom:20px" class="description indicator-hint">Your password needs to be at least seven characters. Mixing upper and lower case, numbers and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ & ) will make it stronger.</p>

<p class="login-username">
<input  type="password" tabindex="10" size="20"  value="" placeholder="New Password"class="input" id="pass1" name="pass1">
</p>

<p class="login-password">
<input  type="password" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="input"   id="pass2" name="pass2">
</p>

<div class="pass-meter"><div id="pass-strength-result" ><?php _e('Strength indicator'); ?></div></div>

<p class="forgotpass-submit">
<a id="forgot-cancel" href="<?php echo home_url('/signin'); ?>">Cancel</a>
<a id="submitforgotpasswordform" href="javascript:void(0)" style="background-position: 0px 4px;"><input type="submit" tabindex="100" value="Get New Password" id="forgot-submit" name="wp-submit"></a>
</p>

<div class="login-error"><div></div></div>

</form>
```

Here is the php code to reset pass on validation in my functions.php:

```
function reset_user_pass(){

parse_str( $_POST['form_values'], $params );

$user = check_password_reset_key($params['key'], $params['login']);

$status='';

// Check if key is valid
if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
    if ( $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' ){
        $status = 'expiredkey' ;
    }
    else{
        $status = 'invalidkey' ;
    }

    echo $status;
    die;

}

// check if keys match
if ( isset($params['pass1']) && $params['pass1'] != $params['pass2'] ){
    $status = 'mismatch';
}else{
// Update the user pass
    reset_password($user, $params['pass1']);

    $status ='success';
}

echo $status;
die;

}


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_reset_user_pass', 'reset_user_pass');
```

And finally here's the AJAX code who is not responding to submit button:

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function() {

// Submit the password reset form via ajax
$( '#resetpassform' ).submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $('.login-error').slideUp();

//check if password fields are empty
if( $('#pass1').val()=='' || $('#pass1').val()=='' ){
    return false;
}

var formData= $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {form_values: formData, action:'reset_user_pass' },
})
.done(function(status) {

    switch(status){

        case 'expiredkey' :
        case 'invalidkey' :
        $('.login-error').html('<div>Sorry, the link does not appear to be valid or is expired.</div>').slideDown();
        break;

        case 'mismatch' :
        $('.login-error').html('<div>The passwords do not match.</div>').slideDown();
        break;

        case 'success' :
        $('.login-error').html('<div>Your password has been reset.</div>').slideDown();
        break;

        default:
        console.log(status);
        $('.login-error').html('<div>Something went wrong.Please try again </div>').slideDown();
        break;

    }

})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});

})


})

})(jQuery)
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Finally the solution was adding the ajax url in a header.php script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

Hope it helps.